# How to send messages to specific user in webSocket?

Tags: websocket

I want to send notifications to specific user with WebSocket. Is it secure and right to use that user's sessionId  or JWT in webSocket connection url , like app/user/{sessionId}/notifications ? If not , what is the right way to implement it ?